# How can i toggle a widget visibility that is in a grid layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgridlayout

I want to do a list that changes it's fields numbers when the user changes a the value of a spinbox.
Something like this:

First 5 fields by default

[image]

Then just 1 field for example

[image]

And if the user wants to change it again, he can put 5 fields again.

I made a GridLayout and a couple of QList, one for the Labels and the other one for LineEdits. I did this:

I create a basic case (with just 1 field) and i later add more on excecution time adding Widgets to the GridLayout by:

```
gridLayout->addWidget(labels.at(x), 0, 1)
```

where labels is the QList. it works fine to add widgets but i can't remove and add again.

i tried using

```
gridLayout->removeWidget(lables.at(x), 0, 1)
labels.at(x)->hide()
label.at(x)->setVisible(false)
```

all works but i can't show it again with none of this:

```
gridLayout->addWidget(labels.at(x), 0, 1)
labels.at(x)->show()
label.at(x)->setVisible(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts are handlers of the geometry of the widgets. If you use the `removeWidget()` function, you will only remove that element from the layout but it will still be visible. If you want it not to be visible you have to delete it with `delete`.

In the following example I show you how to add and remove the widgets using the `valueChanged` signal of the **QSpinBox**.

```
void Dialog::on_spinBox_valueChanged(int arg1)
{

    int nElements = labels.count();

    //add
    if(arg1 > nElements){
        for(int i=nElements; i < arg1; i++){
            QLabel *label = new QLabel(QString::number(i), this);
            QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit(QString::number(i), this);
            labels.append(label);
            lines.append(line);
            ui->gridLayout->addWidget(label, i, 0, 1, 1);
            ui->gridLayout->addWidget(line, i, 1, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    //remove
    else if(arg1 < nElements){
        for(int i=arg1; i < nElements; i++){
            QLabel *label = labels.at(i);
            QLineEdit *line = lines.at(i);
            ui->gridLayout->removeWidget(label);
            ui->gridLayout->removeWidget(line);
            labels.removeAt(i);
            lines.removeAt(i);
            delete label;
            delete line;
        }
    }
}
```

Add:

[image]

Remove:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works, but why i can't just setVisible(false) and later setVisible(true)? 
Supose the Qlist have predefinied values from 1 to 5 (and that is the range of the spinbox).